# Checking a box in a web form with the built in web browser. (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, bots

I'm building a bot that automatically fills in your shipping/payment info for the Supreme website. I have a button assigned to fill in shipping and payment info, I just need it to agree to the terms and conditions as well. Here is what I've tried:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("oder_terms").InvokeMember("Click")
```

That did not work.

Here's my code for the button in full:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("order_billing_name").SetAttribute("value", "xxx") 
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("order_email").SetAttribute("value", "xxx") 
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("bo").SetAttribute("value", "xxx") 
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("order_billing_zip").SetAttribute("value", "xxx") 
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("order_billing_city").SetAttribute("value", "zzz") 
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("order_tel").SetAttribute("value", "xxx") 
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("onb").SetAttribute("value","xxx")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("number_v").SetAttribute("value", "666") 
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("commit").InvokeMember("Click") 
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("order_billing_state").SetAttribute("value", "xx")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("order_terms").InvokeMember("Click")
End Sub
```

Ignore the formatting, reddit got it messed up. whatever.

[here](http://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout)'s the website that I'm getting the element id's from:

Comment: It's been a long time since I've done any VB, but instead of InvokeMember() have you tried SetAttribute("checked", "checked")? I'm assuming the "order_terms" field is a checkbox. You can see the spec where the attribute "checked" is described here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html.

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this 
`WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("oder_terms").Click`